# Opencv/Python executable file creation issue

Tags: python, opencv, exe, pyinstaller, bin

Any one know how to create an executable file for a python project. I have open CV imported in a file , I used PYinstaller to create an executable file, but if i run that executable it is showing that "No module named cv2".Please Help me.

Comment: What version of python, opencv and pyinstaller are you using?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install opencv-python`